# Are there any open source video transcoding servers?

Tags: c#, video, transcoding

Are there any servers written that can be setup to take video transcode jobs?  I am looking to set one up to work just like the service Zencoder.  Something that I could send my transcoding jobs to maybe via web-services.  If not are there any c# wrappers to the common open source transcoders such that I could write one.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.kaltura.com, they have an open source server that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could put FFmpeg on an EC2 instance. Or just use Zencoder and save yourself some time and pain.